# Windows 8 web design

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a Windows 8 sidescrolling style  web design. I need help in scripting the way content appears in a rectangle. The content should scroll down one by one with a slight pause in between headings for the user to be able to view it and alternate the direction after reaching the last heading.

Here us the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    overflow:hidden;
}
span.start
{
    font-size:280%;
    font-family:helvetica;
}
div.spacer
{
    margin-top:50px;
}
div.spacer-left
{
    margin-left:30px;
}
div.box1
{
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div.box2
{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:10px;
}
#cyan
{
    background-color:cyan;
}
#purple
{
    background-color:purple;
}
#lime
{
    background-color:lime;
}
#orange
{
    background-color:orange;
}
#red
{
    background-color:red;
 }
#yellow
{
    background-color:yellow;
}
div.length
{
    position:fixed;
    width:5000px;
    -moz-transition:all 2s;
    -webkit-transition:all 2s;
}
div.click
{
    font-size:500%;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:1300px;
    margin-top:-400px;
}
#length:target
{
    margin-left:-1000px;
}
div.content
{
    position:relative;
    height:500px;
    font-size:200%;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var rate = 0;
function scroll() {
    setInterval(function (){
        document.getElementById('content').style.marginTop = rate;
        rate--;
    }, 10);
}
onload=scroll();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="length" id="length">
<div class="spacer-left">
<span class="start">Start</span>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="box1" id="cyan">
<div class="content" id="content">
<h1>Some content</h1>
<h1>Some more content</h1>
<h1>Even more content</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="box1" id="purple">
</div>
<div class="box2" id="lime">
</div>
<div class="box2" id="orange">
</div>
<br>
<div class="box2" id="red">
</div>
<div class="box1" id="yellow">
</div>
<div class="box2" id="cyan">
</div>
<div class="box1" id="purple">
</div>
<br>
<div class="box1" id="lime">
</div>
<div class="box2" id="orange">
</div>
<div class="box1" id="yellow">
</div>
<div class="box2" id="red">
</div>
<a href="#length"><div class="click" id="click">
>
</div></a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this code, the content is just scrolling but there is no pause in between.

Comment: The Time in the Interval is in milliseconds. For 10 seconds, set 10000.

Comment: No, you didn't understand what i meant. I mean to say that, on page load some content will be displayed in that box. After some time, say 2 seconds a scroll will happen in that box and it will shift to the next piece of content. Then it will remain still for two more seconds and again shift to next content. After going to the last piece of content, the motion will reverse and continue so on forth.

Comment: Then the event might be set in a wrong way. Try body.onload = scroll; Important: No "()"!

Comment: Not that. It's correct. I just need help in making the script for doing the above mentioned stuff. The script which i have made doesn't do any of that.

Answer (score 0):

It will most likely be easier if you use jQuery for the animation. I have a good start on the code for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/ou67gr51/1/

As you see I'm fading instead of sliding. You can easily change that to a different animation.

There is more to do but I hope this helps you out.

```js
$('.box').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $content = $('.content', $this);
    var i = -1;
    function showNext() {
        i++;
        if (i == $content.length)
            i = 0;
        
        $content.eq(i).fadeIn();
    }
    function switchToNext() {
        $content.eq(i).fadeOut(showNext);
    }
    showNext();
    window.setInterval(switchToNext, 2000);
});
```

```css
body
{
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    overflow:hidden;
}
span.start
{
    font-size:280%;
    font-family:helvetica;
}
div.spacer
{
    margin-top:50px;
}
div.spacer-left
{
    margin-left:30px;
}
div.box1
{
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:10px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div.box2
{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:10px;
}
#cyan
{
    background-color:cyan;
}
#purple
{
    background-color:purple;
}
#lime
{
    background-color:lime;
}
#orange
{
    background-color:orange;
}
#red
{
    background-color:red;
 }
#yellow
{
    background-color:yellow;
}
div.length
{
    position:fixed;
    width:5000px;
    -moz-transition:all 2s;
    -webkit-transition:all 2s;
}
div.click
{
    font-size:500%;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:1300px;
    margin-top:-400px;
}
#length:target
{
    margin-left:-1000px;
}
div.content
{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="length" id="length">
<div class="spacer-left">
<span class="start">Start</span>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="box" id="cyan">
<div class="content">
<h1>1 Some content</h1>
</div>
    <div class="content">
<h1>2 Some content</h1>
</div>
    <div class="content">
<h1>3 Some content</h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="box1" id="purple">
</div>
<div class="box2" id="lime">
</div>
<div class="box2" id="orange">
</div>
<br>
<div class="box2" id="red">
</div>
<div class="box1" id="yellow">
</div>
<div class="box2" id="cyan">
</div>
<div class="box1" id="purple">
</div>
<br>
<div class="box1" id="lime">
</div>
<div class="box2" id="orange">
</div>
<div class="box1" id="yellow">
</div>
<div class="box2" id="red">
</div>
<a href="#length"><div class="click" id="click">
>
</div></a>
```